# How to cache cell images in app to don't receive memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to know how to cache images from background cell to don't receive images. these images are used in array in the table view. in `viewdidload` is array which looks like this :

```
Cars *car1 = [Cars new];
car1.name = @"BMW 114i";
car1.price = @"28,000 $";
car1.horsepower = @"102hp (75kW)";
etc...
```

at the bottom of this `viewdidload` is array with objects and it is there about 400+ items so device has little bit problem with it so I got lots of memory warnings

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    CarsCell *cell = (CarsCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell ==nil){
        cell = [[CarsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Cars *cars = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cars = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        cars = [carss objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cars.image];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageView.alpha = 0.8f;
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;

    cell.nameLabel.text = cars.name;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.8f];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: check the size of your image file, you shouldn't use high resolution images as thumbnails.

Comment: they have exactly size which is 600x400

Comment: i meant the size of the image in megabytes

Comment: Size is 100-150kb per image

Comment: Are you sure the imageViews aren't piling up and being readded in your code? This is a common issue. Do this right above `return cell;` and scroll through your table view: `NSLog(@"Subview count is: %d",cell.subviews.count);` `NSLog(@"Content View Subview count is: %d",cell.contentView.subviews.count);` You should not see the count increase if your code is right

Comment: I added to my code and in nslog show still 1...